# What does "another minute" refer to?

Tags: meaning

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban (2004)* movie, Malfoy got attacked by Buffbeak:

> Pansy: Does it hurt terribly, Draco?
>
> Malfoy: It comes and it goes. Still, I consider myself lucky. Madam
> Pomfrey said **another minute** and I could've lost my arm.

What does "another minute" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically means

> Madam Pomfrey said (that if it had gone on) another minute I could've lost my arm.

Comment: @BobbyOmega "It" refers to the same thing as in "Does it hurt terribly, Draco?" Your question doesn't contain enough context to determine what exactly it is.

Comment: Madam Pomfroy is saying that if **the situation had continued for** even another sixty seconds, Malfoy would've lost his arm?

Comment: @BobbyOmega You got it.

Comment: Note that *Malfoy* says that Madam Pomfrey says that Malfoy would have lost his arm.  Do you think Malfoy is telling the whole truth here, or is he *fishing for sympathy*?

Comment: @JamesK The only thing I know is the quoted lines seem to be from _Harry Potter_, something I don't care so much for, so I have no idea who these characters are and what kinds of personalities they have. Judging from the quoted lines, the Malfoy character could be lying and fishing for sympathy, sure.

Comment: @EddieKal that was actually a question for the OP, but anyway, Malfoy is one of the main "bad" characters in Harry Potter, and is certainly exaggerating the extent of his injury.